# "Create App Packages" from Command Line instead of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2022, appx, msix, makeappx

Using Visual Studio 2022 I'm able to successfully create App Packages (MSIXBUNDLE) via a Windows Application Packaging Project.

[image]

Folder strucure/output:

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net

I'm trying to replicate this via the Command Line. I can't seem to find any basic documentation on how to perform this so it can be part of CI?

Answer (score 0):

```
msbuild MyApp.AppPkg/MyApp.AppPkg.wapproj /nologo /nr:false /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=Sideload /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x64" /p:AppxPackageDir="C:\out\BuildTest" /p:platform="x64" /p:configuration="Release"
```

Seems to be working for me!

Comment: What if the application does not use msbuild ? What are the steps that msbuild is running ?